# Strange For-In-Do Results From My Bat File

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, set

I'm wondering why _STR is not set to a new %%A? Thanks.

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b C:\test') DO (
    ECHO %%A
    SET _STR=%%A
    ECHO TEST : %_STR%
REM IF "%%A:~-1"=="/" ECHO %%A  
)
```

my output looks like this...

file1.txt
TEST : folder3
file2.txt
TEST : folder3
folder1
TEST : folder3
folder2
TEST : folder3
folder3
TEST : folder3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_STR will be set to the new %%A, but you can't echo it this way.
Because in a parenthesis block, all percent variables are expanded at the parse time, before the execution will start.
To avoid this you can use delayed expansion, or a CALL trick.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b C:\test') DO (
    ECHO %%A
    SET _STR=%%A
    ECHO TEST : !_STR!
    call ECHO TEST2 : %%_STR%%
)
```

Comment: Great exactly what I needed to know!